# Joint PDF for two independent random variables along $Y=X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose I have two independent random variables $X$ and  $Y$, both have support on $(0,\infty)$.

How do I find the p.d.f. for joint distribution along line $Y=X$?

For simplicity, we can assume both have exponential distribution. Can we just write $y=x$ in the joint pdf so that $f(x,y)=g(y)$?

I would love some insight and correction. Thank you very much!

Comment: http://www.stat.yale.edu/~pollard/Courses/241.fall2014/notes2014/ConditDensity.pdf but it's not a very good "proof".

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if intuitively you’re fishing for something like
$$g(x) = f(x, x)\, /\int_0^\infty\, f(t, t)\, dt.$$

Comment: Yes I was thinking this way, but i don't know how to justify it..

Comment: This is correct, although you should be doing line integration. It doesn't matter here since the factors of $\sqrt{2}$ will cancel, but this doesn't always happen. For example, the conditional pdf of $X$ given $Y=X^2$ equals $$f_{X|\{Y=X^2\}}(x)=\frac{f(x,x^2)\sqrt{4x^2+1}}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,x^2)\sqrt{4x^2+1} dx}$$